# How to use the r-r interval sensor in the Microsoft band SDK?

Tags: android-studio, sensors, microsoft-band

I've been trying to use the R-R interval's sensor in the Microsoft band SDK, but I can't find anything related to the sensor either on the internet and the documantation.

Could you explain me how to use it and/or give an example code?

Answer (score 2):

The SDK documentation provides a sample for the Heart Rate sensor data and the logic is the same for RR interval. Go to section 5, page 17: https://developer.microsoftband.com/Content/docs/Microsoft%20Band%20SDK.pdf

Below are snippets if you are using the Android SDK.

First, create the event listener:

```
BandRRIntervalEventListener rrIntervalListener = new BandRRIntervalEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBandRRIntervalChanged(BandRRIntervalEvent event) {
       // add your logic
    }
};
```

Then register the listener (handle your `BandException`):

```
bandClient.getSensorManager().registerRRIntervalEventListener(rrIntervalEventListener);
```

When you are done, unregister your listener (handle your `BandException`):

```
bandClient.getSensorManager().unregisterRRIntervalEventListener(rrIntervalEventListener);
```

Don't forget to get user consent first, this is very important and the SDK documentation explains how to do that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You will find an example with exactly that in the **BandRRIntervalApp** folder in the [Band Android SDK and samples](https://developer.microsoftband.com/Content/download/Microsoft%20Band%20SDK%20and%20Samples%20for%20Android.zip) package. This includes subscribing to the sensor, displaying the value and getting user consent if necessary.